# Ubuntu 16.04 with external 2560 x 1440 often blacks out

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, external-monitor

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. When I connect it over hdmi to dell 25" 2560 x 1440 screen, it sometimes blacks out the screen. I could not find a certain trigger, but it often happens after displaying a system dialog (such as, when you select save as.. in any program and a saving dialog appears). Then, the screen turns off until I close the dialog (usually with escape key). However, it also happens just at random times, usually every 2 minutes for 4~ seconds.

I am running on integrated haswell GPU. I have gnome-shell installed, but it also happens in Unity.

Anyone has idea what could be a root cause of this? If I am connected to full HD monitor everything works fine (yet I have a feeling that the UI gets slower after while - such as opening of terminal or closing a context dialog takes about 2-3 seconds )

Thanks for any advice!

PS. otherwise, the UI of gnome-shell or unity feels very fast, all the animations are smooth and I don't experience anything wrong with that (even on the external 2.5 resolution screen)

Comment: Can confirm this bug on Lenovo T450s running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with kernel 4.4.0-36-generic at 1440p.
Confirmed with HDMI, DVI and Displayport.
External monitor blacks out several times during a work day, averaging to about 10 times a day.
External monitor will show a floating grid of triangular artifacts near horizontal edges a few seconds before going completely black and a resync/reconnect occurs.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by somehow bad hdmi cabel. Other laptops with windows had no problem, just ubuntu at specific tasks. Anyway, hdmi cabel is to be blamed.

Comment: I have this problem regardless of using HDMI, DVI or DisplayPort